# How to compare a value within a variable with a value in an associative array?

Tags: php

If i've got an array:

```
$grades = array("A+"=>"5", "A"=>"4", "B"=>"3", "C"=>"2", "D"=>"1", "F"=>"0");
```

and i've got a variable:

```
$score = 5;
```

is there a way to compare the value within the `$score` variable and the `$grades` array and store the result in a variable `$grade`?

So in the example above the value in `$grade` should be A+?

Comment: If you can (depending on where the array comes from and what else you're doing with it) an easier way would be to defined the array as: `$grades = ['F', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'A+]`. Then all you need to do to get the grade is: `$grade = $grades[$score]:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `array_flip` to exchanges all keys with their associated values in an array. `array_flip` the array and you can reuse the array multiple times.

```
$grades = array("A+"=>"5", "A"=>"4", "B"=>"3", "C"=>"2", "D"=>"1", "F"=>"0");
$grades = array_flip($grades); 
$score = 5;

echo $grades[$score] . "<br />";
echo $grades[4] . "<br />";
echo $grades[1] . "<br />";
```

This will result to

```
A+
A
D
```

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`array_search()`](https://php.net/array_search) to get the first corresponding key for a value:

```
$grades = array("A+"=>"5", "A"=>"4", "B"=>"3", "C"=>"2", "D"=>"1", "F"=>"0");
$score = 5;
$grade = array_search($score, $grades);
echo $grade; // A+
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$grades = array("A+"=>"5", "A"=>"4", "B"=>"3", "C"=>"2", "D"=>"1", "F"=>"0");
$score = "5";
$grade = "";

foreach($grades as $key=> $val){
    if($score == $val)
        $grade = $key;
}

echo $grade;
```

Answer (score 3):

For an associative array, you have to iterate with the foreach function as following :

```
foreach($grades as $key => $value){
    if($score === intval($value)){
        $grade = $key;
        break;
    }
}
```

for associative array, use : $key => $value. This way in your exemple, during the first iteration, $key will be "A+" and $value will be "5".

For more informations, you can go look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) ;p